# function a.e. differentiable and it's weak derivative

Tags: sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory, weak-derivatives

Note - I am just starting to learn about theory of distributions, so this may be a trivial question, if so I'd be grateful for a reference, nevertheless the question is the following:
suppose I have a function $f$ such that $f \in L^1$ and $f$ is differentiable almost everywhere (in the strong sense) and I'm trying to find whether or not it's weak derivative can be represented by a function $g \in L^1_{\operatorname{loc}}$.

Is it obvious that if such $g$ exists then we must have $g = f'$ a.e.? of course I know it doesn't have to be true that if $f'$ exists a.e. then it's the weak derivative of $f$ since the weak derivative can be for example $\delta_0$ but if all I'm interested in is whether or not the weak derivative of $f$ can be represented as an integration (with respect to the Lebesgue measure) against some function then is it enough to just check whether or not $f'$ works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Useful fact*: a function with locally integrable weak derivative (i.e., a function of Sobolev class $W^{1,1}_{\rm loc}$) is [approximately differentiable](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Approximate_differentiability) almost everywhere, and the approximate derivative agrees with the weak derivative. This is stated on [page 8 here](http://cvgmt.sns.it/media/doc/paper/145/gioantinv.pdf) with a reference to the book by L. Ambrosio, N. Fusco, D.Pallara, *Functions of bounded variation and free discontinuity problems*. Another reference is the book by L.C. Evans and R.F. Gariepy *Measure theory and fine properties of functions*.

If a function has strong (pointwise) derivative at $x$, then this derivative is also the approximate derivative. Hence, if a function is $W^{1,1}_{\rm loc}$ and differentiable a.e., then its weak derivative is represented by the pointwise derivative.

Comment: so we require $f$ to be integrable in the compact sets...this is the best that can be done? to deduce that there is a representative of the generalized derivative we assume that there is a representative in each compact set?