# Weak-Strong Derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, distribution-theory

If a continuous function $u:\mathbb R^d\to \mathbb R$ has a weak derivative $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_j}$ that exists everywhere as a locally integrable function, and it is even continuous, does this imply that the strong derivative $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_j}$ exists and is equal to the weak? Also, let's make this stronger by assuming that the (strong) partial derivatives of $u$ exist almost everywhere. Can we conclude that they exist, in fact, everywhere?

I have seen this topic [function a.e. differentiable and it's weak derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423888/function-a-e-differentiable-and-its-weak-derivative) about approximate derivatives, but I'm asking what we can conclude about the strong derivative, if we are working on weak derivatives.

**Edit:** I know that we are working on a.e. equivalence classes, but what assumptions can we impose on $u$ (weaker than differentiability) so that the strong derivative exists?

**Edit 2:** I found that if the weak derivative exists and it is in $L^p$, $\infty>p\geq 1$, then the strong also exists and it is equal to the weak a.e. However, this only gives a.e. existence. (Source : http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~bdriver/231-02-03/Lecture_Notes/weak-derivatives.pdf , Theorem 19.18)

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/352307/various-kinds-of-derivatives). If the distributional derivatives are given by continuous functions, the classical partial derivatives exist everywhere and coincide with the distributional derivatives.

Comment: This perfectly answers the question, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thread pointed out by Daniel Fischer, [Various kinds of derivatives](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/352307/), indeed concerns this question. But since it is set in $\mathbb R^1$, and the answers involve indefinite integrals, I give another argument for $\mathbb R^d$.

Consider the sequence of [mollified](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier) functions $u_k = u*\phi_{1/k}$. These are smooth and satisfy
$$\frac{\partial u_k}{\partial x_j} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_j} * \phi_{1/k} \tag{1}$$
As $k\to\infty$, the right hand side of (1) converges locally uniformly to $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_j}$. Therefore, $u_k$ converges in $C^1(\Omega)$ norm on every bounded domain $\Omega$. Let $v$ be its limit. At the same time, $u_k\to u$ in $L^1(\Omega)$. Therefore, $u=v$ a.e., which means $v$ is a $C^1$ representative of $u$.

Comment: That's also a very nice way!